# Open a new scratch file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, scratch-file

In PyCharm 4.5, one of the new features is listed as "Temporary Python Scratch Files". How do I create these?

I've searched through the "New" menu and haven't been able to find it. When I select "New...", I am given the option to create permanent files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a scratch file by going to "Tools" -> "New Scratch File..."

[image: New Scratch File Menu Option]

This presents you with the "New Scratch" dialog

[image: New Scratch File Dialog]

If you are a fan of keyboard short cuts, the default for this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

This key combination can be modified by going to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Keymap" and searching for "Scratch"

[image: Modify Scratch pad keyboard shortcut]

Comment: It's not there in the menu for me (2017.2), but the hot key works!

Comment: The "New Scratch File" option was moved to `File → New Scratch File`. (PyCharm 2017.3.3)

Answer (score 4):

You can find any PyCharm command with Help/Find Action menu! It is really useful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PyCharm 2018.2 Community edition on Windows. Now there is an option to create a new scratch file in the context menu when you right-click your project folder as shown below:

[image]

Or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> key combination which shows an explicit context menu meant only for scratch files:

[image]